# How to Override Views Field Handler

Tags: 8, entities

Is it possible to overwrite a Views Field hander without creating a new field?

For example, I am trying to overwrite the Geolocation ProximityField field handler.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Plugin\views\field;

use Drupal\geolocation\Plugin\views\field\ProximityField;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Field handler for geolocation field.
 *
 * @ingroup views_field_handlers
 *
 * @ViewsField("geolocation_field_proximity")
 */
class RangeProximityField extends ProximityField {

  /**
   * Form constructor for the user input form.
   *
   * @param array $form
   *   An associative array containing the structure of the form.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
   *   The current state of the form.
   */
  public function viewsForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $this->viewsForm($form, $form_state);
    // Add custom logic here.
  }

}
```

I tried using hook_views_data_alter() but had no luck (I renamed in above annotation to mymodule_field_range_proximity):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_data_alter().
 */
function mymodule_views_data_alter(array &$data) {
  $data['node__field_latlong']['field_latlong']['field']['id'] = 'mymodule_field_range_proximity';
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to create a new field handler. You can replace the class of the existing field plugin. The plugin manager provides a hook to alter the plugin definitions:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_plugins_field_alter().
 */
function mymodule_views_plugins_field_alter(array &$plugins) {
  $plugins['geolocation_field_proximity']['class'] = 'Drupal\mymodule\Plugin\views\field\RangeProximityField';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to altering that field I just created a new field formatter.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_data_alter().
 */
function mymodule_views_data_alter(array &$data) {
  $data['node']['mymodule_field_proximity_range'] = array(
    'title' => t('Proximity Filter with Range'),
    'field' => array(
      'title' => t('Proximity Filter with Range'),
      'help' => t('Proximity Filter with Range'),
      'id' => 'mymodule_field_proximity_range',
    ),
  );
}
```