# Override a method implemented by a third-party module

Tags: 8, plugins

I want to change something in a method implemented in a third-party module without hacking the module itself, but overriding the method in my module.

The third-party module is views_data_export. I want to change the `attachtTo()` method in the `Drupal\views_data_export\Plugin\views\style\DataExport` class.

```
public function attachTo(array &$build, $display_id, Url $url, $title) {
  // @todo This mostly hard-codes CSV handling. Figure out how to abstract.

  $url_options = [];
  $input = $this->view->getExposedInput();
  if ($input) {
    $url_options['query'] = $input;
  }
  $url_options['absolute'] = TRUE;

  if (!empty($this->options['formats'])) {
    $url_options['query']['_format'] = reset($this->options['formats']);
  }

  $url = $url->setOptions($url_options)->toString();

  // Add the CSV icon to the view.
  $type = $this->displayHandler->getContentType();
  $this->view->feedIcons[] = [
    '#theme' => 'feed_icon',
    '#url' => $url,
    '#title' => $title,
    '#theme_wrappers' => [
      'container' => [
        '#attributes' => [
          'class' => [
            Html::cleanCssIdentifier($type) . '-feed',
            'views-data-export-feed',
          ],
        ],
      ],
    ],
    '#attached' => [
      'library' => [
        'views_data_export/views_data_export',
      ],
    ],
  ];

  // Attach a link to the CSV feed, which is an alternate representation.
  $build['#attached']['html_head_link'][][] = [
    'rel' => 'alternate',
    'type' => $this->displayHandler->getMimeType(),
    'title' => $title,
    'href' => $url,
  ];
}
```

I want to append other parameters in `$url_options`, and apply some logic using the module views_data_export, without writing it directly.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) The only possible answer to this is "maybe" - please edit the question to provide full details of what you want to override, how you've tried to override it already (complete with code samples), what you expected to happen, what actually happened, any error messages you see, and so on. The idea is to make this a well-defined and unambiguous question that will be easy to understand, and useful to future visitors. Once you've added the extra information, pease flag for reopening. Many thanks.

Comment: You can extend and replace the style plugin class, like the field plugin in this question https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/263217/how-to-override-views-field-handler